# Strategy Entry not showing if sell conditions met on the same bar buy was triggered

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Im having problems with my strategy setup.
I have my alert conditions set on the 5 minute chart and trigger conditions set to barstate.isconfirmed.
Problem is that if the conditions are met and the bar has just closed the alert is triggered on the open of the following bar , but if the price takes a sudden dive and the conditions are no longer met then the strategy is not showing as in a positions.

I have attached a screenshot so hopefully you can see what i mean.  The left arrow is the bar where the conditions were met and once that bar closed , on the immediate open of the new bar the alert was sent( The right arrow) .  But on the right bar, because the buy conditions are no longer met and the bar hasnt closed , the strategy doesnt seem to recognise that its in an open  position.

I am referring to higher timeframes and i think the problem might be that at the start of the Hr for a few seconds the buy conditions are met on the 5 , 15  and 60 chart but then  a few seconds later they are not ( if the price take a dive).

The example shown was triggered at 2 seconds after the hr on the 5m chart

Is there a way to add a time delay of 5 seconds after the start of each hour to prevent the strategy from buying on the hr crossover

Also the alerts are set to once per bar

[image]

Comment: It would be great if you will share some code reproducing issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i didnt put any code up, i didnt know what parts might be useful and the script is too big.

I just added a time delay at the start of the next bar to wait a few seconds to check if the conditions are still met and then trigger the alert

```
if barstate.isconfirmed
    Time_Logged := time_close

if (timenow>=(Time_Logged + 3000) and timenow<(Time_Logged + 6000))
     if long_condition_met
            strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long )
            alert(Buy_Message, freq = BuyAlertFreq)
```

Comment: Is this an answer? Or are you trying to respond to the request for code in the comments? If the latter, you should add this to your question.

Comment: @Jeremy Caney  I guess the answer, not sure if it will work or not but going to give it a try.  I think i just need to add a few second delay before the alert message is sent